# tab multiple selected lines of wpf textbox c#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, textbox

I am facing a problem with the text box control in WPF application. 
The problem is that when the user selects multilines of the text and then clicks on tab, the selected lines are deleted instead of being indented to the right. 
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Appreciate any help.
Thanks
Ahmad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle it in the code behind as it is not the default action of a textbox. Many ways you can handle it. You will need to override the PreviewKeyDown and you can set the e.handled to true in order for text to not be overridden.

```
    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbx = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            tbx.Text = tbx.Text.Insert(tbx.SelectionStart, "\t" + tbx.Text.Substring(tbx.SelectionStart));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly have to say that you have to implement that functionality, as the tab key was not made for that in the TextBox.